# Trouble with proving that if $(a_n)_n,(b_n)_n$ and $a_n \le b_n \forall n \ge \nu$ then $\liminf_n a_n \le \liminf_n b_n$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, supremum-and-infimum, limsup-and-liminf

**Theorem:** Let $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}},(b_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \subset \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ be two sequences, and suppose that $\exists \nu \in \mathbb{N}: a_n \le b_n \forall n \ge \nu$. Then:
$$
\liminf_n a_n \le \liminf_n b_n
$$

**My proof attempt**

$$a_n \le b_n \quad\forall n \ge \nu \Longrightarrow \inf_{n \ge k}a_n \le a_k \le b_k \quad\forall k \ge \nu \Longrightarrow  \inf_{n \ge k}a_n \le  \inf_{n \ge k}b_n \quad \forall k \ge \nu$$

$c_k := \inf_{n \ge k}a_n$ and $g_k := \inf_{n \ge k}b_n$ then:

$$
c_k \le g_k \quad \forall k \ge \nu \Longrightarrow \sup_{k\ge h}g_k \ge g_h \ge c_h \quad \forall h \ge \nu  \Longrightarrow  \sup_{k\ge h}g_k \ge \sup_{k\ge h}c_k  \quad \forall h \ge \nu
$$

Now $\liminf_k b_k= \sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}}g_k$ but I have $\sup_{k\ge h \ge \nu}g_k$.

However $$\sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}}g_k \ge \sup_{k\ge h \ge \nu}g_k$$ because on the LHS we are taking the supremum on a set whose cardinality is greater or equal (if $\nu=1$) to the one of the set on the RHS.

Therefore:

$$\liminf_k b_k=\sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}}g_k \ge \sup_{k\ge h \ge \nu}g_k \ge \sup_{k\ge h}c_k $$

**Problem**

But $\sup_{k\ge h}c_k \le \sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}}c_k = \liminf_k a_k$ and then:

$$\liminf_k b_k=\sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}}g_k \ge \sup_{k\ge h \ge \nu}g_k \ge \sup_{k\ge h}c_k  \le \sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}}c_k = \liminf_k a_k$$

which clearly doesn't prove the above theorem.

Where am I doing wrong?

Edit: For this proof attempt I followed the line of reasoning of the answers provided [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1757778/theorem-3-19-in-baby-rudin-the-upper-and-lower-limits-of-a-majorised-sequence-c#:%7E:text=to%20the%20top-,Theorem%203.19%20in%20Baby%20Rudin%3A%20The%20upper%20and%20lower%20limits,those%20of%20the%20majorising%20one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct except that $g_k, c_k$ are an increasing sequence w.r.t $k$ so $\sup_{k \geq 0} g_k = \sup_{k \geq h \geq v} g_k$ and $\sup_{k \geq 0} c_k = \sup_{k \geq h \geq v} c_k$.

Comment: I don't understand why $\sup_{k \geq 0} g_k = \sup_{k \geq h \geq v} g_k$ if $(g_k)_k$ is increasing. Also I'm assuming that $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,4..\}$  without $0$.

Comment: $g_{k+1} \geq g_k$, so its enough to take sup after some $v$ elements and the value of sup remains same since more the value of $k$, larger will be $g_k$.

Comment: For example, let $g_k = k $ then $sup\{1,2,3,4\} = sup\{3,4\}$

Comment: I've finally understood. I was having a confusion in my mind arisen from mixing up the meaning and roles of the various indexes involved.